# Finding bases for the sum and intersection of two subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

$$W_1=\begin{pmatrix}a&a\\\ b&a\end{pmatrix}$$

$$W_2=\begin{pmatrix}c&d\\\ e&0\end{pmatrix}$$

I used the quick way by creating a matrix with bases from $W_1$ and $W_2$. After row reducing, I get a matrix with $4$ pivot columuns. The non pivot column is the column for the intersection. So I get $$\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\\ 1&0\end{pmatrix}$$ for the intersection.

Is this correct? I prefer doing this method over others. Also, what if theres  no free columns( no non pivot columns) ? Does that mean the intersection is $0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks right for the intersection.

If there's no nonpivot columns, the intersection is $0$, because this indicates the columns are linearly independent (but this will not happen so long as you have $5$ vectors in a $4$-dimensional space).